# Method of object to save object itself. Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

Do you have any ideas how to write a method, which will save object itself in MATLAB. I mean something like this:

```
A = CSpam();
A.SaveYourself('test.mat');
B = importdata('test.mat');
A==B % true
```

**Just to stress:**
I know about `save()`, the problem is not to save:

```
A=CSpam();
save('test.mat','A');
B=importdata('test.mat');
A==B % true
```

But to save inside an object. In other words to save I should say which variable to save, but how to save class, when I am inside it.

Comment: What are you looking for that [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) doesn't already do? `save` and [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) should be fine for most situations.

Comment: @excaza How I may save the instance of class, being the method of this instance?

Comment: Well...did you try `save`?

Comment: @excaza question updated. You see the difference between 2 snippets?

Comment: All of your [ordinary methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html) require a self reference, why can't you save that? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: HMM... thanks. Stupid question. P.S. i could not provide Minimal,Complete... in case I have no working code. You are right, just `save('test.mat','obj')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your class as follows:

```
classdef CSpam
    % Properties
    properties
        Value = NaN
    end

    % Constructor
    methods
        function obj = CSpam(value)
            obj.Value = value;
        end
    end

    % Serialization
    methods
        function serialize(this,filename) %#ok<INUSL>
            save([filename '.mat'],'this');
        end
    end

    % Deserialization
    methods(Static)
        function obj = deserialize(filename)
            obj = importdata([filename '.mat']);
        end
    end
end
```

and then run a quick test to see if everything works fine:

```
filename = 'test';

A = CSpam(42);
A.serialize(filename);

B = CSpam.deserialize(filename);

isequal(A,B) % 1
```

The trick is to use the name of the first argument of the method (which, for non-static methods, is always the object itself) as the target of the `save` function.